# celery chord callback on_error missing arguments

Tags: python, celery

TypeError: on_chord_error() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'exc' and 'traceback'.

Using celery 4.3.0

Reading this documentation https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords

```py
chord_head_list = (add.s(i, i) for i in range(4))
    res_chord = (group(chord_head_list) | callback.s().on_error(on_chord_error.s())).delay()
print(res_chord.get(timeout=20))
```

```py
@app.task(name='tasks.callback')
def callback(result):
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> callback {0}'.format(result))
    return result


@app.task(name='tasks.on_chord_error')
def on_chord_error(request, exc, traceback):
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Task {0!r} raised error: {1!r}'.format(request.id, exc))
```

Comment: It works on my computer when `on_chord_error` takes only `original_request_id` parameter. Why? Dunno

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with Celery documentation: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3709
You should change error callback parameters:

```
@app.task(bind=True, name='tasks.on_chord_error')
def on_chord_error(self, failed_task_id, param1, param2):
    print(f"failed_task_id {failed_task_id}")
```

Or:

```
@app.task(name='tasks.on_chord_error')
def on_chord_error(*args, **kwargs):
    print(f"args={args}, kwargs={kwargs}")
```

I'm still missing chord group results